# How to inject entity depencies into a controller in symfony 5.2?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I'm a beginner in symfony and I would like to inject my post entity into a method of my controller.

However, I've the following error fired :

```
Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "post".
```

Here is my code :

```php
/**
 * @Route("/post/article/new", name="new.html.twig")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Posts $posts
 * @return Response
*/
public function newArticle(Request $request, Posts $posts): Response
{
    $post = $posts;
    $article = new Articles();
    $post->setAuthor(1);
    $form =  $this->createForm(PostsType::class, $post);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->em->persist($post);
        $this->em->flush();
        $article->setPost($post->getId());
        $themes = $form->get('themes')->getData();
        $article->setThemes(implode(',', $themes));
        $this->em->persist($post);
        $this->em->flush();

        return  $this->redirectToRoute('home.html.twig');
    }

    return $this->render('post/article.html.twig', [
        'formArticle' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Change your route to /post/{id}/article/new and the id should be the post id so the param converter will get the post object related to this id, or you can just pass the id and search for it by your self

Comment: Which entity do you want to insert? `newArticle` sounds like there is no existing entity to be inserted

Comment: It's not really clear. There are `Post` and `Article` entities, the form manage a `Post` entity. Is `Post` a new entity or an existing one ?

Comment: NicoHaase,  jonas303, Post is a new entity I want to insert to my DB. An article is a post but with specific other field which post entity hasn't. In fact article inherit from post entity my DB structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the Post in the route, like a slug for the id or another unique field.
`@Route("/post/{id}/article/new", ...`

Otherwise Symfony has no idea which Post to load.